# Limit a for each loop in a tag cloud

Tags: php, foreach, limit, tag-cloud

I have the following tag cloud.

```
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
$strAllTags .= $row->caption . ","; 
}

// Store frequency of words in an array
$freqData = array(); 

// Get individual words and build a frequency table
foreach( explode(",", $strAllTags) as $word )
{
// For each word found in the frequency table, increment its value by one
array_key_exists( trim($word), $freqData ) ? $freqData[ trim($word) ]++ : $freqData[ trim($word) ] = 0;
}


function getCloud( $data = array(), $minFontSize = 12, $maxFontSize = 32 )
{
$minimumCount = min( array_values( $data ) );
$maximumCount = max( array_values( $data ) );
$spread       = $maximumCount - $minimumCount;
$cloudHTML    = '';
$cloudTags    = array();

$spread = 55;

foreach( $data as $tag => $count )
{
            if ($count > 4)
            {
    $size = $minFontSize + ( $count - $minimumCount ) 
        * ( $maxFontSize - $minFontSize ) / $spread;
    $cloudTags[] = '[[a style="font-size: ' . floor( $size ) . 'px' 
    . '" class="tag_cloud" href="/home?func=search&searchfield=' . $tag 
    .  '"]]' 
    . htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $tag ) ) . '[[/a]]';
           }
}

return join( "\n", $cloudTags ) . "\n";
}   
echo getCloud($freqData);
?>
```

It works fine, I simply need to limit it to the top 20 results, any ideas as to how to do this best?

Thanks, let me know if you need to see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array isn't already sorted, you can use [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to sort it by the highest results. Then you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to create a new array with just the first 20 array elements:

```
arsort($data);
$data = array_slice($data, 0, 20);
```

`arsort` means "associative reverse sort". This just means that it acts on associative arrays, maintaining their keys, and sorts the array in "reverse" (i.e. high to low) order by it's values.

`array_slice` just "slices" up an existing array. In this example, it says "take the `$data` array, and return a new array containing 20 of its values, starting from the first one.

To address the point you made in the comments about this causing the tags to also be displayed in order by size, when you want them to be random. You can accomplish this by using [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on the array after you grab the top 20 records:

```
arsort($data);
$data = array_slice($data, 0, 20);
shuffle($data);
```

Comment: Where/how would I add that in my code, sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: A better method would be to combine yours and @Shakti's method. Sort it first, then break on 20.

Comment: @Sherif: I added a simple example. Note that I changed the function from `asort` to `arsort` because I was an idiot when I wrote the original answer.

Comment: @JohnP: That might be more of a personal preference thing. I don't really think there's much of a performance difference between the two approaches, and I think using `array_splice` might be a tad cleaner.

Comment: @AgentConundrum I did try your method with arsort, it does work, however now my tag cloud shows in order from bigger to smaller, whereas before the different tag sizes would be randomized. A friend suggests I randomize it afterwards, not sure how I'd do that?

Comment: @Sherif: Good point. You can randomize an array by using the [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function.

Comment: @AgentConundrum thanks, I just found that on Google, trying it out now! I'm almost there but I realized that using the arsort method only returns 20 words, not 20 tags. Tags can have 2 words on the site, for example "nice cars" is one tag, but when I do this I only get 20 words so "nice cars" counts as 2..any ideas?

Comment: @Sherif: Why aren't you tracking each tag as a whole, rather than each word individually? If I were you, I'd base the relative size of each tag in the cloud based on the frequency of the whole tag, rather than its individual words.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but how would I do that?

Comment: I went with interesect + shuffle, it works now! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Take another counter variable and increment in loop and check if it is reached to 20 break the loop

OR

Use array_slice

```
$data = array_slice($data, 0, 20);

foreach( $data as $tag => $count )
{
.....
```

Comment: @shakti I thought of that but wouldn't that simply return 20 results in no particular order? I need the 20 tags to be the most used through-out the caption db, I've edited the original post to show the previous part of code that makes that clearer.

Comment: @Sherif: what do you man by `most used`? Are you talking about sorting of an array?

Comment: @shakti well I tried your solution and it only shows up 10 tags not 20, but if I use ($data, 0, 40) for some reason I do get 20. I'm just not sure whether it really is the top 20 - most used as in when users on the site tag their pictures, the tag cloud should only show the 20 tags that come the most often, then spread those 20 tags from 12px to 32px

Comment: @Sherif: This is so because of this `if ($count > 4)`. The values in array they are greater then 4 will be shown.

Comment: @shakti I'm pretty sure there are way more than 20 words that are used more than 4 times tho. Else why would it work with ($data, 0, 40) ? Sorry again, very new at this.

Comment: @Sherif: Do one thing if it got success `arsort($freqData);$freqData= array_slice($data, 0, 20);
echo getCloud($freqData);
`

Comment: @shakti I get this: `Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array`

Comment: I added it at the very end of my code, basically replaced the final echo with your line

Comment: @Sherif: oops, sorry it should be `arsort($freqData);$freqData= array_slice($freqData, 0, 20); ` added above the `echo getCloud($freqData);`

Comment: Thanks @Shakti, that does work but I will be going with @agentcondundrum's method in the end, intersect allows me ot keep my tags intact!